# Javascript is not executing while loading a php page2 into page1 via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am beginner to php and Javascript. i am facing an issue that is i've a page say page1 which has two input fields and a button(Go).While clicking 'Go' the page2 populates on same page (page1) which has a data table. i am trying to implement JS on that Table BUT JS scripts are not Executing.
(If i have a data table in a single page it works but upper scenario it does not).

Page1(Main page having inputs and button)

```
<script src="../javascript/file_history.js"></script>
<input name="advance_search" type="text" id="advance_search" size="26"  /> 
<input  name="button" type="button" onclick="showFileHistory()" value="Go"  />
```

The Other Page having data table on ajax call through JS

```
 <script src="../javascript/file_history.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/gs_sortable.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TSort_Data = new Array('tbl_filemgtview','s', 'i','f');
     tsRegister();
     alert('This should be pop up');
         </script>  

   <table id="tbl_filemgtview">
    <thead id="thead"> <tr class="viewpage_heading">
      <th>Table heads </th></tr>
       </thead></table>
```

What should be there? or the way of executing Script tags which are getting by pass in page 2?

Comment: Where is your showFileHistory() function

Comment: @vimalpt actually in JS code there is no problem.Issue is its just by passing the <Script> tags...specially the file i want to use is "gs_sortable.js" nd this can be viewed at http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/gs_sortable.js .

Comment: Importing "gs_sortable.js" in Page1 and loading DOM after ajaxComplete will help you

Comment: How are you implementing ajax. Using JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Its because the elements previously were not in the DOM and when you click on the button the elements manipulate the DOM so events firing like

```
$("#test").click(function(){
// Do something
});
```

Wont work, Now to make it work you need to use

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
// Do something
});
```

it would be better if you provide us Code or jsfiddle

Comment: thnx..but its not like this ....Big issue is in page 2 why <Script tags getting by pass...i am unable to understand this scenario.when the page-2 gets invoke the only <script> tags on page-2 by passed...